# Masking a number column with text

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am creating a SharePoint list, with custom columns. I need to use a NUMBER column, but mask each number as text like the below:

Very Satisfied

Satisfied

Dissatisfied

I need each item above to equal a score.

So basically, my user selects Very Satisfied and it shows as Very Satisfied, but in the background, sharepoint knows its value as equaling 3, which i will use to calculate an overall score.

How do i mask the number as being 3 but it shows Very Satisfied instead of the number?

Comment: did you try the rating columns...http://platinumdogs.me/2014/02/12/showing-sharepoint-content-ratings-using-html-calculated-columns/

Comment: Just create an additional calculated column that sets the text values based on the number columns value. Hide the number column from the listview.

Comment: Use JSLink and override the field rending for your custom column. Apply the JSLink to all the forms.